# How to know who is deleting the files/directory

Tags: linux, shell, directory, delete-file, rm

We have a directory /home/test/abc
Sometimes we found that the directory is not present. Most probably it is deleted by someone. We have lots of users who log in and out from the system.
I have checked the bash_history of all the users but nobody seems to have executed the rm command.
I would like to know if there is a way to monitor this directory and notify if a user or a script is trying to modify this directory.
I am using Centos

Comment: You could write a wrapper for `rm` or maybe implement the [_sticky bit_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) to `/home/test/abc` (`man chmod`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

You can install a utility that called [acct](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=acct%20utility%20for%20linux&oq=acct%20utility%20for%20linux&aqs=chrome..69i57.10234j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=what%20is%20acct%20in%20linux) (psacct), to monitoring on    the user's activity on your machine.

You can install a tool that called [inotify-tool](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=what%20is%20inotify-tool%20in%20linux&oq=what%20is%20inotify-tool%20in%20linux&aqs=chrome..69i57.5242j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and after that, run the command: `sudo inotifywait -m <your_file_path_here>`, and it will monitor on your file activity in LIVE.